# Raspberry Pi camera not working properly while executing python script

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

When I execute this code manually via 'python makeimg.py' everything is fine and server receives new image, but when I try to do this automatically via crontab

```
*/1 * * * * python Desktop/makeimg.py
```

the diode of camera is on, I can see camera preview for 2 sec, but image is not captured. Does anyone know what is the problem? It worked properly a few days ago, but now it doesn't.

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera
import requests
import datetime

BASE = "http://192.168.0.122:5000/sendimg"

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
sleep(2)

ctime=datetime.datetime.now()
time=ctime.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S')
time=str(time)

camera.capture('images/img_'+time +'.jpg')
sleep(2)

with open ('images/img_'+time +'.jpg', 'rb') as file:
    print('Rozpoczecie przesylania')
    dict = {'file': file}
    r = requests.post(BASE, files=dict)
    print("Wyslano obraz")
    exit()
```

Comment: Could be a working folder issue. Try to use full absolute paths.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help

Comment: You didn't say which user's crontab you put it in. You may have installed some Python module just for one user but called the script from another user. You should use a proper shebang. You may be using the wrong Python version. Try adding some debug statements to your code that *"touch"* files in `/tmp`.